# How to whitelist Google Ads (my website blocks all non-Australia visitors)

Tags: google-ads

Google Ads says my ad destinations are not working.

They are working, but the website blocks non-Australian visitors due to the phenomenal amount of spammers clicking on my ads and filling out contact forms offering to help with SEO.

Is there a list of IPs for Google (Ads) servers I can whitelist to let Google "see" my website and know the ad destinations are working?

Adjusting the geo-targeting in Google Ads doesn't help; spammers use an Australia VPN to see my ads, which costs my ad campaigns money and wastes my time with spam.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Do these blocks actually stop Google counting the ads as clicks - I would imagine not.

Answer (score 2):

From your information, I'm assuming you are blocking non-australian visitors **by IP**, and thus you are having this issue.

Google has more than 9 million IPs only on the IP4 range, and 1.66 × 10^30 for IP6 addresses. While certainly you can create a whitelist of them all, it's impractical no to mention difficult to maintain.

Your best bet is to either identify them by **User Agent** or by **AS number**.

- Adsense uses the following user agent: **Mediapartners-Google**
- Google uses the AS number: **15169**

Implementing a whitelist using the user agent is the easiest.

For the AS number, you'll need a lookup in a GeoIP database, or use a WAF that provides it directly (for example CloudFlare).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would whitelist Google via user agent in .htaccess?